# How to map json response from one object type to another with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am unable to map the response received into an typescript observable object of different type for return.

```
login(entity: AppUser): Observable<AppUserAuth> {
    // Initialize security object
    this.resetSecurityObject();

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('username',entity.userName);
    params.append('password',entity.password);
    let options = { 
      'headers':headers,
      'search':params
    };
// receive and convert the JwtToken to AppUserAuth observable and 
     return
    this.http.get<JwtToken>(API_URL,options).map()...
```

I would like to return Observable of type AppUserAuth

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: please add more detail http get return and what object do you want to map

Answer (score 0):

Hello you set returning data type in function login is `Observable<AppUserAuth>`, but it must be the same with return expression. In return you set `Observable<JwtToken>`.
Good luck!